# How to implement dropdown list of user for sharing of file in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i have created model,

```
class share_files(models.Model):
    files = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    from_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    to_user = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=user_list,default=None)
```

but i want to_user and files as choice fields.
and i want implement dropdown for column to_user and files.
for example, in dropdown of to_user list of user will come from django model User.

and form is

```
class Share_file(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = share_files
        fields = ('files', 'to_user')
```

how to proceed?